# Localize JSON response

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am creating backend for mobile application targeting multiple languages. I choose ASP.NET Web Api to do it.

I am using Entity Framework to access SQL database. To store strings that need to be localized I use class **LocalizedString**:

```
[ComplexType]
public class LocalizedString
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Russian { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string English { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Current
    {
        get
        {
            //Need to implement
        }

        set
        {
            //Need to implement
        }
    }
}
```

Client application specifies requiring language with HTTP header:

```
Accept-Language: ru-RU
```

After I can access requested language within Controller Action:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    //Derives from DbContext
    private DataContext db = new DataContext();

    public ClassWithLocalizedStringProperty GetLocalizedString()
    {
        string language = Request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.FirstOrDefault().Value;
        //Need to implement
    }
}
```

**I would like to minimize data transfer between server and client so I need to send only string of specified language.**

As I understated it can be done at serialization stage or perhaps while accessing SQL Database (with possible changes of LocalizedString class)

I have an idea to implement JsonConverter for LocalizedString class to choose the right string. But I don't know how to inform JsonCoverter that we need specific language.

**Solution:**

Here is my solution that still is not perfect. I use **HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers** within JsonConverter to serialize specified language.

```
[ComplexType]
[JsonConverter(typeof(LocalizedStringJsonConverter))]
public class LocalizedString
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Russian { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string English { get; set; }        
}


public class LocalizedStringJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var localizedString = value as LocalizedString;
        switch (HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Accept-Language"].Substring(0,2).ToLowerInvariant())
        {
            case "ru":
                writer.WriteValue(localizedString.Russian);
                break;
            case "en":
            default:
                writer.WriteValue(localizedString.English);
                break;
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(LocalizedString) == objectType;
    }
}
```